# How to split string into java and android or add spaces while showing in UI

Tags: java, android

While calling this function item.getSymbol(), it returns data in this format.

```
ITC22JAN200PE
HINDUNILVR22JAN2300PE
ASIANPAINT22MAR2500PE
```

UI also shows same format in android.

```
holder.binding.symbolNameTextView.setText(item.getSymbol());
```

I want to show symbols in UI like this.

```
ITC 22JAN 200PE
HINDUNILVR 22JAN 2300PE
ASIANPAINT 22MAR 2500PE
```

How to add spaces after stock name and expiry?

Answer (score 0):

Regex seems the way to go:

```
final String pattern = "(^\\D+)(\\d+(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC))(.*$)";
final String spaced = item.getSymbol().replaceAll(pattern, "$1 $2 $3");
holder.binding.symbolNameTextView.setText(spaced);
```